# Keras CNN + Google Colab always predicts class 1 (High Training + Validation Accuracy)

Tags: keras

Hi I am using the below code to train a classifier in Keras but while testing for new images i am always getting predicted class as 1 although my validation test is showing above 80% accuracy. Please suggest what am i doing wrong.

Code:

```
classifier=Sequential()

#--------------- 2. Convolution --------------------------
classifier.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(64,64,3),filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),activation='relu'))
#--------------- 3. Max Pooling --------------------------
classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
#--------------- 4. Convolution --------------------------
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),activation='relu'))
#--------------- 5. Max Pooling --------------------------
classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
#--------------- 4. Convolution --------------------------
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),activation='relu'))
#--------------- 5. Max Pooling --------------------------
classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
#--------------- 4. Convolution --------------------------
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=256,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),activation='relu'))
#--------------- 5. Max Pooling --------------------------
classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
#--------------- 6. Flattening ---------------------------
classifier.add(Flatten())

#--------------- 7. Full Connection ----------------------
classifier.add(Dense(units=128,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.6))
classifier.add(Dense(units=96,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.4))
classifier.add(Dense(units=64,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer='uniform'))

#--------8. Deal with the weights and Loss function --------
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#-------- 9. Fitting CNN with Images --------
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/training_set',
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=128,
        class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=128,
        class_mode='binary',
        shuffle=False)
filepath="bestcatvsdogmodel.h5"
save_best_model=ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
ReduceLR=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', factor=0.6, patience=5, verbose=2,cooldown=1, min_delta=0.0020, min_lr=0.)
classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=7928/128,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=2000/128,
        callbacks=[ReduceLR,save_best_model])
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
class_labels={v:k for k,v in training_set.class_indices.items()}
img_d=imread('dog.jpg')
img_c=imread('cat.jpg')
img_d=resize(img_d,(64,64))
img_c=resize(img_c,(64,64))
img_dog=np.expand_dims(img_d,axis=0)
img_cat=np.expand_dims(img_c,axis=0)
if(np.max(img_dog)>1):
    img_dog=img_dog/255.0
if(np.max(img_cat)>1):
    img_cat=img_cat/255.0
prediction_cat = classifier.predict_classes(img_cat)
print("Cat Prediction: "+str(prediction_cat))
prediction_dog = classifier.predict_classes(img_dog)
print("Dog Prediction: "+str(prediction_dog))
```

Results:

[image]

Please suggest if you see any error in the code

Comment: FYI: I have checked the dataset and it is quite balanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing

```
prediction_cat = classifier.predict_classes(img_cat)
print("Cat Prediction: "+str(prediction_cat))
prediction_dog = classifier.predict_classes(img_dog)
print("Dog Prediction: "+str(prediction_dog))
```

In your model, I can see that last layer have 1 node, activated with `sigmoid`. Such a model on calling predict gives an output probability ranging from `0` to `1`.

You are calling `predict_classes` on the model. What it basically does is something like `np.argmax(model.predict(test))`. So in your case, as the model is only giving a vector of 1D the output will be always `1`.

For your model to get the output properly you have to use `model.predict()` like shown below.

```
prediction_cat = classifier.predict(img_cat)
print("Cat Prediction: "+str(prediction_cat))
prediction_dog = classifier.predict(img_dog)
print("Dog Prediction: "+str(prediction_dog))
```

Then you will get output something like this

```
Cat Prediction: 0.05
Dog Prediction: 0.98
```

You can use a threshold to map the predicted probabilities to class labels. A commonly used threshold is `0.5` but it is advised to select the threshold based on `f1-score`. Since your dataset is balanced you don't have to worry about it that much. You can make a prediction and map to the class label like shown below. Assuming you encoded `cat` as `0` and `dog` as `1`

```
# suppose test contains image to predict
threshold = 0.5
pred = model.predict(test)
if pred > threshold:
    print('Dog')
else:
    print('Cat')
```

Comment: Thanks Sreeram, your analysis is correct and now i am able to get correct predictions.